# How to pass props to component's story?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook

I wanted to add some stories for [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select) component using [Storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook), but I'm struggling with more complicated cases, which involve passing props or methods.

When I pass props **inside the template it works**:

```
storiesOf('VSelect', module)
.add('with labeled custom options', () => ({
        components: {VSelect},
        template:   `<v-select :options='[{value: "CA", label: "Canada"}, {value: "UK", label: "United Kingdom"}]' />`
    }))
```

I find it not very readable, so I wanted to pass them separately as props or data:

```
.add('with labeled custom options as props', () => ({
        components: {VSelect},
        props:      {options: [{value: "CA", label: "Canada"}, {value: "UK", label: "United Kingdom"}]},
        data:       {options: [{value: "CA", label: "Canada"}, {value: "UK", label: "United Kingdom"}]},
        template:   `<v-select />`
    }))
```

but neither **`data`, nor `props` are not recognized** by storybook - they seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've solved it.

```
.add('with labeled custom options as props', () => ({
        components: {VSelect},
        data() {
            return {
                options: [{value: "CA", label: "Canada"}, {value: "UK", label: "United Kingdom"}]
            }
        },
        template:   `<v-select :options="options" />`
    }))
```

There were 2 problems with my former approach:

- Passed `data` was not wrapped in a function
- I should have pass `data` only. 
  Using both `props` and `data` seems to make Vue return a warning (The data property "options" is already declared as a prop.) and ignore passed `data` (even though it's just a warning not an error, which I find odd)

Comment: If you want props (from storybook knobs) to be reflected dynamically into the component's props, you can use computed. Example: `props: { KnobTitle: { default('Title', 'Title Text') } }, computed: { componentProp() { return { ComponentTitle: this.KnobTitle }; } }, template: '<MyComponent :my-prop="componentProp">'}`